# How do I quote within a comment box?

Tags: support, comments, formatting

As the title says, how do I quote within a comment box? There is a [editing help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) page for this, I know that. But it says I can use angle brackets (>) to create a "simple blockquote". But I tried it and it didn't work. Why is it not simple?...

By the way, what does the "block" quote refer to here?

I could of course just "use regular quotation marks" but I would like to stylize it a little bit to make it more appealing to the eye and easier to find and read.

And what I'm trying to quote is a simple text line from a website, not the users who post answers or comment on answers or qustions.

Comment: you could _italicize_ them or use `backticks`

Comment: I would prefer italics for the sake of separating code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The editing help page that you're looking at is for the most part only relevant to post bodies, the [Comment Formatting](https://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) bit at the end is what you need. And, you'll see that comments use a *very* limited sub-set of markdown.

You can also see the basics by pressing the "help" link that is available under the *Add Comment* button.

So, the style options you have are **bold**, *italic* and `code`.
Personally, I'll sometimes use code to quote someone in a comment, depends on the context, etc.

---

And, since you ask, a blockquote is a just quote formatted in to a separate block.

> They look something a bit like this.

Comment: Thanks! Now is there a sandbox where I can fiddle with this? And also, another reason why "block" quotes don't work in comments because I can't get a line break, correct? If I press Return or Enter key it only saves the comment as is. Of course, even if line breaks were allowed I wouldn't be able to use quotes since they are not supported in comments.

Comment: You can play around in the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) on MSO if you like. I'd advise posting your own answer and commenting on that, to avoid pinging other users. And indeed, comments are intentionally kept compact and simple - the important action should be kept in the question/answer where ever possible.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Comments are treated as second class citizens throughout the network, as such the formatting options in comments are limited. You could you could *italicize* them or use `backticks` to highlight the points